# get offsetHeight of angular child component from parent

Tags: angular

What is the best way to get computed angular child components height from parent? I have a component like below

```
    import { Component, ViewChild } from 'angular2/core';  

    (...)

    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: `
        <h1>My Add Angular 8 app</h1>
       <ng-container *ngFor="let item of list>
          <child #Children [content]="item.content" [id]="id"></child>
       <ng-container>
        <button (click)="submit()">Submit</button>
      `,
    })
    export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit { 
      @ViewChild(Children) Children: QueryList<ElementRef>;

      (...)
      ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log("The children are", this.Children.toArray()) 
        /*==> give me aray of Child component with the props , id and content, 
        i need the computer nativeElement to be able to get the height. */
      }

    }
```

Please what is the best way to get the child components offsetHeight from the parent ? Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can set read metadata rroperties to ElementRef to get offset of child element

**Try this:**

```
 @ViewChildren('Children',{read:ElementRef}) Children: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

**Or**

You have Inject ElementRef service inside Child component so that you can child component nativeElement Inside parent component

**child.component.html**

```
 constructor(public ele: ElementRef){

  }
```

**parent.component.html**

```
@ViewChildren('Children') Children: QueryList<ChildComponent>;

   ngAfterViewInit(){ 
    console.log(this.Children.toArray()[0].ele.nativeElement.offsetTop);
   }
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jvfcqh)

Comment: thanks for the help. While it returns the nativeElement, the heights and widths are 0 all the time. Is there something else i am missing ?

Comment: set child element host display:block

Comment: styles: [`:host { display: block }`]

Comment: Thanks. Although i can see yours works, i tried everything and mine didn't work. Its always 0.

Comment: Cab you create stackblitz?